# Facing this Problem on my Firebase Storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

On Dec 13, 2021, the Firebase Storage team received multiple reports of object upload and preview errors from clients of several major ISPs in Korea: KT, SKT, LG U+. These ongoing errors are the result of an ISP-side domain block of firebasestorage.googleapis.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

We've seen reports from users and developers in Korea about being unable to access data in Cloud Storage through Firebase SDKs or otherwise.

This seems to be happening before the requests hit our infrastructure, so I recommend reaching out to the relevant ISPs and asking them to investigate.